# foreach function in sparkr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am relatively new on SparkR, and I am planning to transfer a for loop into a foreach loop in SparkR (R/3.3.3 & Spark/2.2.0).

I have searched on stackoverflow, the only relevant thread is:
[SparkR foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816328/sparkr-foreach-loop)

But it gives only the workaround by using other operations.

From what I see, there is a `sparkr` package exist (https://amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg/rdocs/1.2/index.html) and contains `foreach` function, but I really do not understand its use cases, which I will need some help/example from the community to help.

My example in original R code is following:

```
uniqueID <- unique(dataset$ID)
maxValueVector <- c()
for(id in uniqueID){
    maxValueVector <- c(maximums, max(dataset[which(dataset$ID == id), ]$value))
}
```

I understand that the line in for loop should be break into several lines, but is there an example I can start with, such as the example `foreach` code I can start with? Thanks a lot!

p.s. `dataset` contains 2 columns: `ID` and `value`.

Comment: a) That's really not how we express things in Spark. b) SparkR package you've linked have been abandoned many years ago, and even if it wasn't, its `foreach` wouldn't be applicable here. For new API see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html (Hint: focus on [`groupBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/groupBy) docs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments said, in SparkR, we generally do not want to use foreach. In this particular case, I found the answer using `sparkdataframe` operatiors and solved this problem:

```
## IDs is collected fo
IDs <- collect(distinct(select(dataset, 'ID')))
## I added the maximums column in order to figure out the future steps
## it basically satisfied what I need to have.
Maximums <- agg(groupBy(dataset, dataset$ID), maximums = max(dataset$value))
Maximums <- arrange(Maximums, desc(Maximums$maximums))
```

I know since I am still new on this, so this solution may not be what you are looking for. But thanks again for comments!